# Rolling Sum on Spark Dataframe filtered by other column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, calculated-columns

I have a spark dataframe looking like this, containing a single row for every combination of articlenumber, countrycode and date where a value in amount exists for that combination. There are about 400,000 rows in this dataframe.

```
articlenumber   countrycode   date         amount
--------------------------------------------------
4421-222-222    DE            2020-02-05   200
1234-567-890    EN            2019-05-23   42
1345-457-456    EN            2019-12-12   107
```

Now I need an additional column "amount 12M" that calculates its value for each row according to the following rules:

In every row, "amount 12M" should contain the sum of all values from 'amount' where articlenumber and countrycode match to the ones from that specific row and where the date lies in between the 12 months before the date in that row.

Do I need to add rows with the amount 0 for date/country/articlenumber combinations that haven't got a value yet?

As I'm not quite an expert in programming (engineering student) I need some help how to achieve this within the python script which deals with that dataframe.

Thank you for any ideas on this.

Comment: pandas right? not spark.

Comment: oops my fault. the person working on it before i did uses both but as far as i understand it's a spark dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('articlenumber', 'countrycode').orderBy('date').orderBy('yearmonth').rangeBetween(-11, 0)

df.withColumn('yearmonth', f.expr('(year(date) - 2000) * 12 + month(date)')) \
  .withColumn('amount 12M', f.sum('amount').over(w)) \
  .orderBy('date').show(10, False)

+-------------+-----------+----------+------+---------+----------+
|articlenumber|countrycode|date      |amount|yearmonth|amount 12M|
+-------------+-----------+----------+------+---------+----------+
|4421-222-222 |DE         |2019-02-05|100   |230      |100       |
|4421-222-222 |DE         |2019-03-01|50    |231      |150       |
|1234-567-890 |EN         |2019-05-23|42    |233      |42        |
|1345-457-456 |EN         |2019-12-12|107   |240      |107       |
|4421-222-222 |DE         |2020-02-05|200   |242      |250       |
+-------------+-----------+----------+------+---------+----------+
```

---

I am not sure about the exact 12 months but this will work.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('articlenumber', 'countrycode').orderBy('unix_date').rangeBetween(- 365 * 86400, 0)

df.withColumn('unix_date', f.unix_timestamp('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd')) \
  .withColumn('amount 12M', f.sum('amount').over(w)) \
  .orderBy('date').show(10, False)

+-------------+-----------+----------+------+----------+----------+
|articlenumber|countrycode|date      |amount|unix_date |amount 12M|
+-------------+-----------+----------+------+----------+----------+
|4421-222-222 |DE         |2019-02-05|100   |1549324800|100       |
|4421-222-222 |DE         |2019-02-06|50    |1549411200|150       |
|1234-567-890 |EN         |2019-05-23|42    |1558569600|42        |
|1345-457-456 |EN         |2019-12-12|107   |1576108800|107       |
|4421-222-222 |DE         |2020-02-05|200   |1580860800|350       |
+-------------+-----------+----------+------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Works for me with one exception: We decided to use data only on a monthly basis, so all dates in date column are yyyy-mm-01. As we want the code to include the last 12 months that means if a date in a row is 2020-05-01 we want included for that rows 12m-value all data back to 2019-06-01. Therefore I updated the code so that it reaches only 350 days back. But now it seems to struggle as soon as this period includes a leap year. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: you can calculate the months from some bias (i.e. 200001) to the current and use this column.

Comment: When running your code like above @Lamanus I now get an error: 
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" 
in line 6 of your edited code. What can I do?

Comment: what about this? `(cast(year(date) as int) - 2000) * 12 + cast(month(date) as int)`

Comment: Results in the same error at the same position, anything else that could cause this?

Comment: well, year and month functions return integer so I think this is not the problem of my code. You might miss something.

Comment: Solved it, function "sum" was imported under another name...sorry for the confusion and thank you for your coding, works perfectly fine.